# Difficult integral - speed up numerical integration using a trick?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, integration, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-integration

I have the following integral that I need to solve (with high precision) millions of times in my simulations. This is time consuming and is prohibiting me from proceeding from proceeding forward.

I see little possibility to solve it in closed form, but I mostly wonder if it is possible to manipulate it so that I can numerically integrate it quicker.
Perhaps a confusing question, but simply put: How should this be evaluated quickly?

$$\int_{-B}^B\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(d_1+x^2+y^2)^{3/4}}\frac{1}{(d_2+(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2)^{3/4}}\quad \times\exp\left(2\pi i\left(\sqrt{d_1+x^2+y^2}-\sqrt{d_2+(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}\right)/\lambda\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y.$$

where $d_1$, $d_2$, $x_0$, $y_0$, and $\lambda$ are positive constants.
I noted one thing that may be of some help:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(d+x^2)^{3/4}}\frac{1}{(d+(x-x_0)^2)^{3/4}}\quad \times\exp\left(2\pi i\left(\sqrt{d+x^2}-\sqrt{d+(x-x_0)^2}\right)/\lambda\right)\mathrm{d}x  = K\mathrm{sinc}(2x_0/\lambda),$$
where $K$ is a constant that depends on $d$ (forgot exactly what it was)...

Comment: Can you find an expression for the integral in your help, with $d+(x-x_0)^2$ replaced by $ (d_2 + (x-x_0)^2)$ ? It seems one might get something using residuals, but the details seem horrendous, so I am not going to try. Another idea is to make a change of variables from $x$ to $u = \sqrt{d+x^2}-\sqrt{d_2+(x-x_0)^2}$ and see if the result is a known Fourier transform. At least that will reduce the integration to one variable over $[-B,B]$.

Comment: I recommend asking this on scicomp.SE.  Also, you should mention what method you are using now, and which implementation of it.